# dense generators and left Kan extensions

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Here is an exercise from [Borceux, Handbook of Categorical Algebra I](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YfzImoopB-IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=borceux+handbook+of+categorical+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LHVtU46ACsSU0AX1n4HABg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=borceux%20handbook%20of%20categorical%20algebra&f=false), p 174:

> Consider a category $\mathfrak{C}$, a family $(G_i)_{i \in I}$ of objects of
>   $\mathfrak{C}$ and the corresponding full subcategory 
>   $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathfrak{C}$.
>   Prove that $(G_i)_{i \in I}$ is a dense family of generators if and only if
>   the left Kan extension of $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathfrak{C}$ along
>   $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathfrak{C}$ is the identity on $\mathfrak{C}$

I think i can prove the "only if" part, but for the "if" part i need to 
take homset indexed products in $\mathfrak{C}$ (e.g. by assuming
$\mathfrak{C}$ is locally small and has all products), my effort reproduced below.

I have two questions: Is the result really true in general, if so why? And if 
the result is not true in general then how would you go about finding a
counterexample?

The effort (with details proving naturality etc ommitted for brevity) is as follows:

Let $H : \mathcal{G} \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{C}$ be the
injecting functor. Say the Kan extension of $H$ along $H$ is the identity. 
Since $H$ is full
and faithful we can take the corresponding natural transformation $H \rightarrow
H$ as the identity.

Take $C$ in
$\mathfrak{C}$ and let $\Gamma_C : (\mathcal{G} \downarrow C) \rightarrow 
\mathfrak{C}$ be the canonical projection, and $\gamma_C : \Gamma_C \rightarrow
\Delta C$ be the canonical cocone. Let $\theta : \Gamma_C \rightarrow \Delta
D$ be any other cocone. The goal is to show that
$\hat{\theta} : C \rightarrow D$ exists uniquely such that $\theta =
\Delta \hat{\theta} \cdot \gamma_C$

We set the "inputs" to the Kan extension situation as follows: Let $K : \mathfrak{C} \rightarrow \mathfrak{C}$ be
the functor that takes each object $X$ to $\prod_{f : X \rightarrow C} D$ and
arrows $g : X \rightarrow X'$ to the unique $K(g)$ such that $\pi_f \cdot K(g)
= \pi_{f \cdot g}$ for all $f$. Let $\phi : H \rightarrow K \cdot H$ be the natural
transformation such that $\pi_f \cdot \phi_{G_i} = \theta_f$ for all $f$.

We then "exploit" the Kan extension situation as follows: Given any
$\hat{\theta} : C \rightarrow D$ such
that $\Delta \hat{\theta} \cdot \gamma_C = \theta$ we can set
a natural transformation $\hat{\phi} : \text{id}_{\mathfrak{C}} \rightarrow
K$ given by $\pi_f \cdot \hat{\phi}_X = \hat{\theta} \cdot f$ for all $f$. 
Then $\phi = \hat{\phi} H$, and $\hat{\theta} = \pi_{\text{id}_C} \cdot
\hat{\phi}_C$ so $\hat{\theta}$ is provided and determined uniquely by the
Kan extension.

In general then, $\gamma_C$ is a colimit as required. Now ... did i really
need to take those products to get this out?

Comment: For pointwise Kan extensions the claim is almost a tautology.

Comment: I guess so but to compute a left Kan you need $\mathfrak{C}$ co-complete, right?

Comment: If you assume that, it boils down to proving a specific formula for left Kan extensions. See Proposition A.5.25 in [my notes](http://zll22.user.srcf.net/writing/homotopical-algebra/2014-05-15-Main.pdf), for example.

Comment: I cant help thinking that's what the author intended after all.